# Html > Redirect to a new Page and Refresh the Main Page where the Button is

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create a Button using HTML and CSS with this Code

```
<article>
    <span class="image">
        <img src="images/test.jpg" alt="" />
    </span>
    <header class="major">
        <h3><a href="#" class="link" >Test</a></h3>
        <p>Test</p>
    </header>
</article>
```

I want the following to happen when you click this Button:

A new link opens in a new Tab (I know that you can do this with target="_blank" and when you go to the new tab, the page where this button is gets reloaded / refreshed.

I tried a few things with JavaScript but nothing worked.

Here is what I tried:

```
<h3><a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.yahoo.com', '_blank')();window.location.href=window.location.href();" class="link" >Teamspeak</a></h3>
```

Comment: Show us your JavaScript attempt and perhaps we can help.

Comment: If you are using jQuery then try to use `location.reload();` on a link click. This will reload the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h3><a href="#" class="link" onclick="window.open('http://google.com', '_blank'); window.location.href=window.location.href">Test</a></h3>
```

Because href is not a function. No need of parenthesis. In your javascript code href is used as href().
Please remove the extra pair of parenthesis after window.open function also.

Answer (score -1):

Call a javascript function from `<a onclick="javascript:fn ()" >load </a>.`
From that function, open this url and do window.location.reload () to reload current page.